# How to right align with positive symbol and comma separator in Python print?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to right align, have a positive sign where the value is positive, and comma separate thousands but can't quite get there.

I'm trying to get, e.g.:

```
green    +1,000
blue     -2,000
```

But when I do

```
"{:<8} {:+>10,}".format("green", -1000)
```

the left spaces are filled with `+` regardless of whether it is a positive or negative value, like:

```
'green    ++++-1,000'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried replacing format string `"{:<8} {:+>10,}"` to `"{:<8} {:>+10,}"`? Does that give the expected output?

Comment: That's the one. Thanks! If you can post as an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [format string documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), you should have the sign goes after the alignment. In this case, you should change the format string from

```
"{:<8} {:+>10,}"
```

to

```
"{:<8} {:>+10,}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with clear funtion

```
chr="green"
space=" "   
val="-1000"
print(f"{chr}{space*(8-len(chr))}{space*(10-len(val))}{val}")
```